# Fibonacci Pairs

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Find all positive integer solutions to 
$y^2 - xy - x^2 = 1$ and  $y^2 - xy - x^2 = -1$

I have written a C++ program to yield some solution for large constants. I must make conjectures based on the output.
I notice that the output resembles the Fibonacci sequence.

My code http://cpp.sh/7qsjw

I know that the ratio between the $F_{n}$ and $F_{n-1}$ terms is approximately equal to $\frac{1+5^{1/2}}{2}$, the Golden Ratio.  Are there more conjectures to this problem.

Comment: If we put $y=F_{n+1}$ and $x=F_n$, we get alternately the first equation and the second. The relevant identity is I think called Cassini's Identity, and is not difficult to prove by induction.

Comment: There is a set of numbers that satisfy this pair of simultaneous equations.  This system does not contain one closed solution.

Comment: Your code is wrong. The second `1` should be a `-1`. Anyway, the system has no solution because it is $E=1$ and $E=-1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you just expand a little bit more.  Do not provide any proofs.

Comment: The relevant identity is something like $F_{n+1}F_{n-1}-F_n^2=(-1)^n$. (Note that my exponent may be off by $1$.) This is I think called Cassini's identity. Using $F_{n+1}=\dots$, this can be rewritten as $F_{n-1}^2+F_{n-1}F_n-F_n^2=(-1)^n$, which looks very much like your equation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas am I in the right to think that I have to prove the identity that you've provided for the odd and even numbers, separately?

Comment: Not separately,  it will be a standard induction proof and the sign will change "naturally."

Comment: @AndreNicolas Can you provide a hint to the Inductive Hypothesis?

Comment: @Bayerischer: I wrote out the induction as an answer, easier than doing it in comments, which are too cramped for math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the indexing $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$ for the Fibonacci numbers. We want to show that 
$$F_{n+1}^2-F_{n+1}F_n-F_n^2=(-1)^n.$$
The result holds at $n=0$. Suppose it holds at $n=k$. We show the result holds at $n=k+1$. So the induction hypothesis is 
$$F_{k+1}^2-F_{k+1}F_k-F_k^2=(-1)^k,\tag{1}$$
and we want to show that
$$F_{k+2}^2-F_{k+2}F_{k+1}-F_{k+1}^2=(-1)^{k+1}\tag{2}.$$
In the left side of (2), replace $F_{k+2}$ by $F_{k+1}+F_k$. We obtain
$$(F_{k+1}+F_k)^2 -(F_{k+1}+F_k)F_{k+1}-F_{k+1}^2.\tag{3}$$
Expand and simplify. We get
$$F_k^2+F_{k+1}F_k-F_{k+1}^2,\quad\text{that is,}\quad
-(F_{k+1}^2-F_{k+1}F_k-F_k^2).$$
By the induction hypothesis this is $-(-1)^k$, which is $(-1)^{k+1}$. That completes the induction step.

*Remark*: We have shown that consecutive Fibonacci numbers alternately satisfy one of the two given equations. We have not shown that consecutive Fibonacci numbers are the *only* solutions of these equations in non-negative integers. But that is true, and follows from general facts about Pell-type equations.

Comment: For $ a,b \in N,$ with $a>b\geq 1$ ,we have $|a^2-a b-b^2|=1\implies$ $ |b^2-b c-c^2|=1$, where $c=a-b.$  And also $b\geq 2 a$. So let $a=A_0 , $ $b=A_1$, and $A_{n+2}=A_n-A_{n+1}.$ The largest $m$ for which $A_m>0$ must satisfy $A_m=A_{m-1}=1.$ Working backwards from this, we see that $(b,a)$ is a consecutive  Fibonacci pair.

Comment: @user254665:  Nice. I thought in general terms, showing that any solution is a "power" of the fundamental solution. But that idea can be made very concrete in this case.

Comment: @AndreNicolas Jesus Christ.  I was darn close before you replied. Thank you.

Comment: @AndréNicolas what if you were to define $F_0 = 1$ instead of $F_0 = 0$. I do not think it alters your answer much, am I right?

Comment: Just changes my $(-1)^n$ to $(-1)^{n+1}$, but fundamentally nothing changes. Bur note that $y=1$, $x=0$ really is a solution of the Diophantine equation, and if we declare $0$ not to be a Fibonacci number, then one solution is not a Fibonacci pair. All *positive* solutions, however, are then Fibonacci pairs, so nothing much is lost.

Answer (score 1):

The following constitutes a proof that you get Fibonacci pairs for both problems...

```
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental_A
2  1
1  1


  3^2 - 5 1^2 = 4

1 x^2 + -1 x y -1 y^2 = 1

Mon May  2 12:07:33 PDT 2016

x:  2  y:  1 ratio: 2  seed 
x:  5  y:  3 ratio: 1.666666666666667
x:  13  y:  8 ratio: 1.625
x:  34  y:  21 ratio: 1.619047619047619
x:  89  y:  55 ratio: 1.618181818181818
x:  233  y:  144 ratio: 1.618055555555555
x:  610  y:  377 ratio: 1.618037135278515
x:  1597  y:  987 ratio: 1.618034447821682
x:  4181  y:  2584 ratio: 1.618034055727554
x:  10946  y:  6765 ratio: 1.618033998521803
x:  28657  y:  17711 ratio: 1.618033990175597
x:  75025  y:  46368 ratio: 1.618033988957902
x:  196418  y:  121393 ratio: 1.618033988780243
x:  514229  y:  317811 ratio: 1.618033988754322
x:  1346269  y:  832040 ratio: 1.618033988750541
x:  3524578  y:  2178309 ratio: 1.618033988749989
x:  9227465  y:  5702887 ratio: 1.618033988749908

Mon May  2 12:07:53 PDT 2016
2  1
1  1
Inverse of given automorphism of quadratic form:
1  -1
-1  2
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= 

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental_A
2  1
1  1


  3^2 - 5 1^2 = 4

1 x^2 + -1 x y -1 y^2 = -1

Mon May  2 12:09:30 PDT 2016

x:  1  y:  1 ratio: 1  seed 
x:  3  y:  2 ratio: 1.5
x:  8  y:  5 ratio: 1.6
x:  21  y:  13 ratio: 1.615384615384615
x:  55  y:  34 ratio: 1.617647058823529
x:  144  y:  89 ratio: 1.617977528089888
x:  377  y:  233 ratio: 1.618025751072961
x:  987  y:  610 ratio: 1.618032786885246
x:  2584  y:  1597 ratio: 1.618033813400125
x:  6765  y:  4181 ratio: 1.618033963166706
x:  17711  y:  10946 ratio: 1.618033985017358
x:  46368  y:  28657 ratio: 1.618033988205325
x:  121393  y:  75025 ratio: 1.618033988670443
x:  317811  y:  196418 ratio: 1.618033988738303
x:  832040  y:  514229 ratio: 1.618033988748204
x:  2178309  y:  1346269 ratio: 1.618033988749648
x:  5702887  y:  3524578 ratio: 1.618033988749859

Mon May  2 12:09:50 PDT 2016
2  1
1  1
Inverse of given automorphism of quadratic form:
1  -1
-1  2
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```